# Where can my question regarding image editing / Photoshop go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Isn't Doctype for web design? Where will my Photoshop questions go? And isn't photography for photographers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's about the manipulation of a photograph then https://photo.stackexchange.com/ would be a good home. The site isn't just for professional photographers. From their [FAQ](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Photography - Stack Exchange is for professional and amateur photographers.

If it's about Photoshop usage in general then https://superuser.com/ should accept your question.

Comment: here's my question on superuser http://superuser.com/questions/179646/photoshop-converting-bitmap-to-shape

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about using Photoshop to make Web Design, [Doctype](http://doctype.com/) is the place to ask your question.

For photographic editing, there is the website [Photography and Photographic Editing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) that is in open beta. As long as it is related to editing image, I think it will be on-topic for that site.

Comment: The Doctype link now says "Doctype closed on the 15th of February 2013". Time to update?